# unable to ssh to an instance after boot. Using fog with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fog

I am having trouble connecting to an EC2 instance right after I bootstrap it using Fog. After bootstrapping I wait for the instance to be ready and then wait 5 extra seconds. However I still am unable to connect via ssh. The connection is available after a bit, but it takes a bit after the machine is 'ready'.

```
instance.wait_for { ready? }
instance.wait_for { !public_ip_address.nil?}
sleep(5)
```

Any suggestion on a way to wait for the machine to be ready to accept ssh connections?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using EC2, make sure that the Security Group the server is in allows SSH on port 22. If you are not on EC2, it may be a similar firewall issue.

EDIT:  Here is some code I've used before and never had any issues with, but that was with a non-ec2 cloud provider.

```
def wait_for resource, msgOnStart, msgOnReady='Done'
  print msgOnStart
  resource.wait_for do
    print '.'
    if resource.ready?
      print "#{msgOnReady}\n"
      true
    end
  end
end

@server = compute.servers.create(#blahblahblah)
wait_for @server, 'Provisioning server'
```

Comment: I can ssh after a while. It just takes a bit. The question is more how do I determine when I am able to connect.

Comment: What cloud provider are you using?

Comment: I've added some code that worked for me with a non-ec2 provider to my answer